# Can Java Predicates check a database?

Tags: java, predicate

I work with existing code I'd like to extend. An existing UsernameValidator that takes a predicate to verify username and password. It also does some more checks in addition, which I do not want to change.

I'd like to have a database with usernames and hashed passwords to verify against. Can I somehow construct a Predicate that does that?

Comment: Yes, you can ... good luck

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course. Just query the database from the predicate. You might need a `BiPredicate`, not a `Predicate`, however.

Comment: Thank you! What would the second argument of the BiPredicate be? The database file?

Comment: Username and password.